# how to control UIApplicationShortcutItems title & icon location

Tags: ios, uiapplicationshortcutitem

[image]

[image]

How can control this? I have try to change the location in the plist.

Comment: sorry . I have resolve this question . i found that if your app in the right of the screen , the icon in the left if your app in the left , the icon in the right. it can not be controlled by developer

Answer (score 4):

sorry . I have resolve this question .
i found that if your app in the right of the screen , the icon in the left
if your app in the left , the icon in the right.
it can not be controlled by developer.